# Label in colorbox not clickable

Tags: jquery, html, label, colorbox

I have simple [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox) loaded with:

```
$.colorbox({html: $('#widget-login').html()});
```

The content of colorbox is a form (input + label):

```
<form name="f-login" id="f-login" action="#" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="f-email">e-mail:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="f-email" />
        <input type="submit" value="go" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

When I click on label "e-mail", I should get focus on `f-email` input, but nothing happens. What I'm doing wrong?

FF 17.0.1

Comment: You should set a jsfiddle maybe, im not sure what you are looking for.

Comment: The code works fine, here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wV5N5/

Comment: On a side note, it's not necessary to close the input tags with /> in HTML 5. Using '>' is sufficient.

Comment: Colorbox doesn't work in jsfiddle (if i'm not mistaken). Anyway problem solved (see below) my post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this is what you are asking for but try this out..

```
$(label['for="f-email"').click(function(){
       $('#email').focus();
    });
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V3QeR/)..

Answer (score 1):

colorbox has nothing to do with form elements.

please add this in header file of your form html. Since you dont have any ID to your label, im typing $('label')
else you can give label a ID and then track it with jquery below. Also, you can get the idea of jquery, its simple.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// put all your jQuery code in here.
    $('label').on('click', function(){
       $('#f-email').focus();
    });
});;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved :]

I edited my question, there is significant update: `html` not `href` in colorbox trigger. In this case there are 2 elements with same ID – one in hidden div, second in colorbox.

Thanks all and sorry for wasting your time.